# Tensorflow code copied straight from (popular) book does not converge:

Tags: python, tensorflow

The below code is copied straight from the book "Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit learn and Tensorflow" on page 237.

```
n_epochs = 10000
learning_rate = 0.01
X = tf.constant(housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
theta = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([n + 1, 1], -1.0, 1.0), name="theta")
y_pred = tf.matmul(X, theta, name="predictions")
error = y_pred - y
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(error), name="mse")
gradients = 2/m * tf.matmul(tf.transpose(X), error)
training_op = tf.assign(theta, theta - learning_rate * gradients)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(n_epochs):
        if epoch % 100 == 0:
            print("Epoch", epoch, "MSE =", mse.eval())
        sess.run(training_op)
    best_theta = theta.eval()
```

Here, the data housing_data_plus_bias is a normalized data-set, the same one used by the book but I normalized it myself using the following code.

```
housing = fetch_california_housing()
m, n = housing.data.shape
housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m, 1)), housing.data]

means = []
vars = []
for col in range(n):
    means.append(np.mean(housing_data_plus_bias[:, col]))
    vars.append(np.std(housing_data_plus_bias[:, col]))


for row in range(m):
    for col in range(n):
        if col == 0:
            continue
        housing_data_plus_bias[row, col] = (housing_data_plus_bias[row, col] - means[col])/vars[col]
```

But the code does NOT converge, see output below. It produces NANs instead. Why would the book say it works when it doesn't?

Is it perhaps because of the following output I get in the console, which showcases a number of errors?

output:

[image: output]

Finally, you can see the page from the actual book HERE and verify that I have copied it exactly:
[book image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOJJ3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using the wrong version of Tensorflow, or have not correctly installed its dependencies. `NaN` is probably the result of these issues. Double check the version the book uses and `pip install tensorflow==<version>`, replacing `<version>` with the version the book uses.

You can see the version you're running by running `pip list | grep tensorflow`.

For a more specific answer, could you show more of the errors you're seeing in the console? The code looks fine to me.